# How to remove bottom nav bar on main activity from fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

On clicking on the notification, fragment appearing on screen has bottom navigation bar. And I want to remove it as it is not in fragement.
Please help me.
`

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(requireContext())
           .setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.mobile_navigation)
            .setDestination(R.id.navigation_pairAnimation)
            .createPendingIntent()
```

`
Basically, I have 3 fragments attached to a bottom navigation bar.
And on failure of bluetooth connection. I have to display a notification which leads me to pairing fragment. But on clicking on it , screen is showing me fragment along with bottom navigation bar which I don't want to show.Also it was not there when first time pairing fragment appears.

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to understand you. You have set up your Main Activity to host fragments but you don't want it to appear on clicking the notification? Kindly give a more detailed info so that we can help you